# Finding Mode of Vector of Ints in C++

Tags: c++, function, random, vector, mode

So I'm trying to make a basic program to learn the basics of C++, I'm generating 100 random numbers from 0 to 100 and storing them in a vector, I am then displaying the sum, mean, median, mode, high and low of the vector. I have everything else done except the mode which is where I get stuck. Here is the code I have so far.

```
int modeFunction()
     {
         numMode = 0;
         count = 0;
         for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
         {
             for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
             {
                 if (numVector.at(y) == numVector.at(n))
                {
                    numMode = numVector.at(y);
                    count++;
                }
             }

         }
         return numMode;
     }
```

After that I get stuck because in my mind that should work but it doesn't. It just out puts the last number, usually 100. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if `myVector` is a `std::vector<int>` (seems like it atleast), you can index it like an array: `myVector[y]` and `myVector[n]` will yield the same as the `myVector.at` version, but looks nicer imho. :)

Comment: @Xeo: the difference being that `at` has defined behaviour when the index is out of range. Arguably `operator[]` is a micro-optimization, although as you say it's also a bit of a style difference.

Comment: @Steve: Ah, thanks for that tidbit. :) Didn't bother with `at` yet, but a normal array also has undefined behaviour for out of range access, though it certainly is nice to have defined behavious when you need it. :)

Comment: @Xeo: to be honest, I never use `at` myself. I occasionally wonder whether I should, but in practice I never write code that I want to throw an exception when the index is out of bounds, so it only serves as a debugging assist, it "should" never happen. Despite calling it a micro-optimization, it's a reasonable amount of redundant code, so in the end if I want bounds-checking I just switch to Python ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

since all the values are between 0 and 100, you can find the mode efficiently with a histogram:

```
std::vector<int> histogram(101,0);
for( int i=0; i<100; ++i )
  ++histogram[ numVector[i] ];
return std::max_element( histogram.begin(), histogram.end() ) - histogram.begin();
```

Comment: Would this not work for values outside of [0,100] (this should work for any symmetric histogram, no?)

Answer (score 4):

Since mode is the number that occurs most frequent you shouldn't change `numMode` unless the new number's count is greater than `numMode`'s count.

EDIT: To clarify, you need to keep a separate count for the current element and the current number that you think is the mode. Ideally, setting `newMode` to the first element is a good approach.

In addition, mode isn't necessary unique (i.e. "1 1 2 2"). You may want to keep that in mind if you care about that.

```
newMode = element[0]
modeCount = # of occurrence of newMode

for ( i-th element from [1 to end] ) {
   tmpCount = # of occurrence of element[i]
   if tmpCount > modeCount {
     newMode = element[i]
     modeCount = tmpCount
   }
}
```

Comment: I am who downvoted. I did it because this answer is incomplete as it assumes the array of number of occurrences of the values is known, however, this array is the most important here.

Answer (score 3):

bmcnett's approach works great if number of elements are small enough. If you have large number of elements but the all element value are with in a small range using map/hashmap works well. Something like

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> mode_pair;

struct mode_predicate
{
  bool operator()(mode_pair const& lhs, mode_pair const& rhs)
  {
    return lhs.second < rhs.second;
  }
};

int modeFunction()
{
  std::map<int, int> mode_map;
  for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    mode_map[numVector[n]]++;
  mode_predicate mp;
  return std::max_element(mode_map.begin(), mode_map.end(), mp)->first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is wrong - it outputs the last number in the array because that's all it can ever do.  Every time the number at index `y` matches the number at index `n` you overwrite the results for the previous `n`.  Since you're using the same loop conditions, `y` and `n` are *always* the same at at least one point in the nested loop for each possible `n` value - and you'll always end up with `numMode` being `numVector.at(99)`.

You need to change your algorithm to save the count for each `n` index along the way (or at least which `n` index ended up with the greatest `count`), so that you can know at the end of the `n` loop which entry occured the most times.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solutions. Note: untested.

```
int mode1(const std::vector<int>& values)
{   
    int old_mode = 0;
    int old_count = 0;
    for(size_t n=0; n < values.size(); ++n) 
    {
        int mode = values[n];
        int count = std::count(values.begin()+n+1, values.end(), mode);

        if(count > old_count) 
        {
            old_mode = mode;
            old_count = count;
        }
    }
    return old_mode;
}

int mode2(const std::vector<int>& values)
{   
    return std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end(), [](int value)
    {
        return std::count(values.begin(), values.end(), value);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think in `mode1()` you should compare `count + 1` with `old_count` because you start counting from the position one after the position of the counted value: i.e. you must add the initial one to `count`.

Comment: Moreover, I think it's not a good practice to assign the initial value for the value with the searched property as `0`. It should be better to use the first element for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Mode means a number with highest frequency. The logic should be -

```
//Start of function

int mode = 0, globalCount = 0 ;  
// Start of outer for loop
for i = 0 to length - 1    
   int localCount = 0   

  // Start of inner for loop  
  for j = 0 to length - 1      
     if vec[i] == vec[j]    
     ++localCount    
 // End of Inner for loop 

 if ( localCount > globalCount )  
     globalCount = localCount  
     mode = vec[i]  
// End of outer for loop  

if globalCount > 1 // This should be checked whether vec has repetitions at all
   return mode
else
   return 0

// End of function
```

Comment: @Cistoran - The logic can be even better improving efficiency but this is what the algorithm should be according to your thought process.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int number = array_list[0];
    int mode = number;
    int count = 1;
    int countMode = 1;

    for (int i=1; i<size_of_list; i++)
    {
          if (array_list[i] == number) 
          { // count occurrences of the current number
             count++;
             if (count > countMode) 
                {
                      countMode = count; // mode is the biggest ocurrences
                      mode = number;
                }
          }
          else
          { // now this is a different number
                if (count > countMode) 
                {
                      countMode = count; // mode is the biggest ocurrences
                      mode = number;
                }
               count = 1; // reset count for the new number
               number = array_list[i];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have sorted vector with integers.
Iterate over the vector and accumulate repeatments if current value equals to next one.
If neighboring values are not equal, reset current repeatment to 1 and continue the loop.
Along the way store and update max repeatments.

```
vector<int> nums;
int mode = 1;
for (int i = 0, cur_reps = 1; i < nums.size(); i++)
{
    if (i < nums.size()-1 && nums[i] == nums[i + 1])
    {
        cur_reps++;
        continue;
    }
    if (cur_reps > mode) mode = cur_reps;
    cur_reps = 1;
}
```