# Finding the mode of n numbers

Tags: c++, mode

I'm trying to write a program, in which the user gives n numbers and the program has to find out which number is being repeated the most.
for example for numbers : 4 5 5 1 3 1 1 7 1 the answer is 1
I'm a beginner by the way, so that's why most of the answers which were already on the site didn't suit me.
I'd be very thankful.

Comment: OMG, search StackOverflow first:  "c++ find mode"

Comment: Either show your code, and describe the specific issue or this will be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316352/how-do-i-find-the-mode-of-an-array

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That question asks about a sorted array, and I've adjusted its title to reflect that.

Comment: So, I didn't list all the results from the search: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+find+mode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb

Comment: @Sara, you might want to use a `std::vector` as per my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hashmap (`unordered_map`) to count the occurrences of the numbers, then search the maximum occurrence count in the hashmap.

Comment: The overhead of hashing is not required here; an `std::map` would suffice.

Comment: Using a std::map increases the algorithmic complexity to O(n log n), whereas using a hashmap is O(n). n O(1) inserts and one O(n) search vs n O(log n) inserts. Have you ensured, that insertion into std::map is faster than into std::unordered_map?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use a priority queue it will holds the elements {1,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,7}
and then manipulate the mode from this queue

Answer (score 0):

What you probably would want to do is insert the numbers into a `std::vector`, use `std::sort`
(in `<algorithm>`) on it, and loop through it so see which number occurs the most times. 
To give you an idea, you may use `std::vector<int>::iterator` while looping (use *`auto`* instead) to point to the beginning + 1 of the vector, then check if the value to which the iterator points is equals to
 `iterator - 1`. If the current value is **higher** than **max value** then store it, along with an iterator to that object.

Hope that helps you on the way.